# Rails momentary SCSS compilation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

(Rails 5.1 on Windows 10) When I modify the SCSS file (app/assets/stylesheets/mystyle.scss), I get this error (**Error compiling CSS asset - Permission denied @ utime_failed**) in Chrome when immediately reloading the page which references it. If I load the page in the browser again, it works fine. I appreciate that the SCSS needs time to run but have not seen this (bad) behaviour before. Any suggestions?

[image]

I notice this different error when doing the same in Edge, which then gets replaced with the same error as above on the second attempt and then is fine on attempt #3:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem's disappeared. I think it was due to the SCSS file being included in the **require_tree .** manifest but the CSS file was also being referenced a few lines later in the HEAD. I noticed this and removed the second (CSS) reference.